# string concatenation, log4cplus, and MISRA compliance

Tags: c++, misra, log4cplus

I am using `log4cplus`, and my misra-checks for something as innocent-looking as

```
LOG4CPLUS_INFO(
        logger,
        std::string("ABC") + std::string("DEF"));
```

yield (among others) `` The underlying type of `0L` is implicitly reduced from `8-bit signed char` to {code{bool}}. ``. This happens also when I put the respective literals rather than wrapping them inside `string`. I wonder how to fix this. Or, more generally put, how would you concatenate several log messages and yet keep MISRA-checks happy?

Comment: MISRA allows the use of concantenating two strings. I am unfamiliar with log4cplus but it could be invoking a macro which MISRA does not like. Alternatively if it doesn't complain about one message then just construct the string beforehand and pass in the concatenated string.

Comment: This macro does not seem to fin into any of MISRA approved use case categories:  *"C++ macros shall only be used for include guards, type qualifiers, or storage class specifiers."*

Comment: @user7860670 Well  dynamic memory shouldn't be used either and `std::string` uses that, there are many things it does not allow

Comment: Indeed... why are you using std::string in a MISRA application? Not to mention that evil-looking function-like macro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a look at `LOG4CPLUS_INFO` and that is a macro defined as:

```
#if !defined(LOG4CPLUS_DISABLE_INFO)
#define LOG4CPLUS_INFO(logger, logEvent)                                \
    LOG4CPLUS_MACRO_BODY (logger, logEvent, INFO_LOG_LEVEL)
```

and `LOG4CPLUS_MACRO_BODY` is defined as:

```
 #define LOG4CPLUS_MACRO_BODY(logger, logEvent, logLevel)                \
     LOG4CPLUS_SUPPRESS_DOWHILE_WARNING()                                \
     do {                                                                \
         log4cplus::Logger const & _l                                    \
             = log4cplus::detail::macros_get_logger (logger);            \
         if (LOG4CPLUS_MACRO_LOGLEVEL_PRED (                             \
                 _l.isEnabledFor (log4cplus::logLevel), logLevel)) {     \
             LOG4CPLUS_MACRO_INSTANTIATE_OSTRINGSTREAM (_log4cplus_buf); \
             _log4cplus_buf << logEvent;                                 \
             log4cplus::detail::macro_forced_log (_l,                    \
                 log4cplus::logLevel, _log4cplus_buf.str(),              \
                 __FILE__, __LINE__, LOG4CPLUS_MACRO_FUNCTION ());       \
         }                                                               \
     } while (0)                                                         \
     LOG4CPLUS_RESTORE_DOWHILE_WARNING()
```

and so your MISRA checker will be checking the invocation of the macro. And MISRA likes `if` statements to be defined explicitly in terms of `bool` e.g. rather than `if(node)` it likes `if(node!=nullptr)` and I think it may have an issue with the last line:

```
     } while (0)                                                         \
```

As `0` is being implicitly cast to `bool`. You should see if you get the same warning by adding a simple `do{}while(0);` loop to your code and run your checker again.

---

And if you want a MISRA safe way of logging, I would avoid the use of macros. You can make a simple logging class with a `std::ofstream` and a `std::mutex` and keep it in namespace scope defined as an extern in your header file.

Comment: True, I've also found this out, looking into the source code of the log4cplus library...

Comment: Let me add that log4cplus's macros are only a convenience. You can implement whatever logging means you want with the methods of the API without any macros.